# SQL - Select All rows with Value X when a Row has Value Y

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get data from a row, then look up all rows with the data from that row.

My Table is like this:

```
Invoice    Desc          Item_Code     Units     Price     Amount
1000       PHASE A       45            10        20        200
1000       BOLTS         16            45        1         45
1000       Jerry         10            1         100       100
1001       PHASE B       19            10        5         50
```

I want to return all rows with whatever is in Invoice when Desc is LIKE PHASE A.

I know enough to write:

```
SELECT 
Invoice, Desc, Item_Code, Units, Price, Amount
FROM tbl
WHERE
Desc LIKE '%PHASE A%'
```

This will only return the row containing PHASE A - I want every row of PHASE A as below:

```
1000       PHASE A       45            10        20        200
1000       BOLTS         16            45        1         45
1000       Jerry         10            1         100       100
```

I feel like that should be in a IN statement, or I need to append an IN statement, but don't know where it should go.

Comment: DESC is a reserved word, so I guess you don't know enough even for that  ;-)

Comment: Shortened table for ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel like that should be in a IN statement, or I need to append an
>   IN statement, but don't know where it should go.

Here

```
SELECT Invoice,
       Desc,
       Item_Code,
       Units,
       Price,
       Amount
FROM   tbl
WHERE  Invoice IN (SELECT Invoice
                   FROM   tbl
                   WHERE  Desc LIKE '%PHASE A%')
```